# No difference between Savitzky-Golay 2nd order and 3rd order polynomial curve

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, time-series, smoothing

I don't understand why there is no difference between Savitzky-Golay 2nd order and 3rd order polynomial curve? Perhaps the 3rd order polynomial curve is overfitted, not sure but the concern is yet not unambiguous until I would plot the 2nd order curve. Would anyone fix the code for 2nd order polynomial?

I have attached my code below:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/7ba9ccf18a4da7887c6f060a8e7d769c

and part of it:

```
var pt = ee.Geometry.Point(80.634, 21.75).buffer(500)
Map.centerObject(aoi, 5)


// real NDVI values 
var NDVI = function(image) {
  return image.expression('float(b("NDVI")/10000)')
};

//Rescale
var rescale = function(image) {
  return image.divide(10000).copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start", "system:time_end"])
}

// get the date and convert to DOY

function returnDate(image) { 
  var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).getRelative('day','year').add(1).toFloat();
  return image.addBands(ee.Image.constant(date).select([0],['DOY']).int16());
}


var start_date = '2020-03-01'
var end_date = '2021-06-30'  // the Future

var Mod_col = modis.filterDate(start_date, end_date).filterBounds(pt)
.select(['NDVI', 'EVI'])
// .map(returnDate)
.map(rescale)
print(Mod_col,'Mod_col')



// Add predictors for SG fitting, using date difference
// We prepare for order 3 fitting, but can be adapted to lower order fitting later on
var modis_res = Mod_col.filterDate(start_date, end_date).filterBounds(aoi).map(function(img) {
  var dstamp = ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start'))
  var ddiff = dstamp.difference(ee.Date(start_date), 'hour')
  img = img.select(['NDVI', 'EVI']).set('date', dstamp)
  return img.addBands(ee.Image(1).toFloat().rename('constant')).
    addBands(ee.Image(ddiff).toFloat().rename('t')).
    addBands(ee.Image(ddiff).pow(ee.Image(2)).toFloat().rename('t2')).
    addBands(ee.Image(ddiff).pow(ee.Image(3)).toFloat().rename('t3'))
})

print(modis_res, 'modis_res')


print(Chart.image.series(modis_res.select('NDVI'), pt, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500)//.select('NDVI')
    //.setSeriesNames(['fitted'])
    .setOptions({
      title: 'NDVI_timeseries',
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 3,
}));

// Step 2: Set up Savitzky-Golay smoothing
var window_size = 9
var half_window = (window_size - 1)/2

// Define the axes of variation in the collection array.
var imageAxis = 0;
var bandAxis = 1;

// Set polynomial order
var order = 3
var coeffFlattener = [['constant', 'x', 'x2', 'x3']]
var indepSelectors = ['constant', 't', 't2', 't3']

// // Change to order = 2 as follows:
// var order = 2
// var coeffFlattener = [['constant', 'x', 'x2']]
// var indepSelectors = ['constant', 't', 't2']

// Convert the collection to an array.
var array = modis_res.toArray();
print(array, 'array')

// Solve 
function getLocalFit(i) {
  // Get a slice corresponding to the window_size of the SG smoother
  var subarray = array.arraySlice(imageAxis, ee.Number(i).int(), ee.Number(i).add(window_size).int())
  var predictors = subarray.arraySlice(bandAxis, 2, 2 + order + 1)
  var response = subarray.arraySlice(bandAxis, 0, 1); // NDVI
  var coeff = predictors.matrixSolve(response)

  coeff = coeff.arrayProject([0]).arrayFlatten(coeffFlattener)
  return coeff  
}


// For the remainder, use modis_res as a list of images
modis_res = modis_res.toList(modis_res.size())
print(modis_res,'modis_res size')


var runLength = ee.List.sequence(0, modis_res.size().subtract(window_size))
print(runLength, 'runLength')

// Run the SG filter over the series, and get the smoothed image 
var sg_series = runLength.map(function(i) {
  var ref = ee.Image(modis_res.get(ee.Number(i).add(half_window)))
  return getLocalFit(i).multiply(ref.select(indepSelectors)).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()).copyProperties(ref,['date','system:time_start'])
})

print(sg_series, 'sg_series')

print(Chart.image.series(sg_series, pt, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500)//.select('NDVI')
    //.setSeriesNames(['fitted'])
    .setOptions({
      title: 'NDVI_SG_timeseries_3rd Order',
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 3,
}));
```